# Jboss 6.0.0 final Deployment issue with CXF 3.3.1

Tags: ant, jboss, cxf, web-deployment

I am using Jboss 6.0.0 final.Existing cxf version used was cxf 2.2.3

I am trying to upgrade my cxf to 3.3.1.

Resolved my build issue. I have all cxf 3.3.1 libraries inside my war file.
Following are the errors while deploying in Jboss.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Is there any way where I can upgrade default cxf in jboss 6.0.0 final to cxf 3.1.1 ?

Please help !!

> 11:20:10,075 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
>   11:20:13,312 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfs:///D:/Project/Softwares/APP/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/APP.war state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///D:/Project/Softwares/APP/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/APP.war
>       at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
>       at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
>       at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.8.0_40]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error visiting "/D:/Project/Softwares/APP/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/APP.war/WEB-INF/lib/cxf-core-3.1.1.jar/org/apache/cxf/common/util/ReflectionUtil$10.class"
>       at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:268) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
>       ... 43 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error visiting resource: VFSResourceContext @ org/apache/cxf/common/util/ReflectionUtil$10.class / BaseClassLoader@2488e3ee{vfs:///D:/Project/Softwares/APP/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/APP.war}, visitor: org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.GenericAnnotationVisitor@38846e5b
>       at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.IgnoreSetErrorHandler.handleError(IgnoreSetErrorHandler.java:56) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:91) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.AnnotationsScanningPlugin.visit(AnnotationsScanningPlugin.java:89) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       ... 56 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Enclosing method not found
>       at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:1065) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.scope.ClassScope.computeEnclosingScope(ClassScope.java:50) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.getEnclosingScope(AbstractScope.java:76) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:94) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:94) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.findTypeVariable(CoreReflectionFactory.java:110) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitTypeVariableSignature(Reifier.java:165) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature.accept(TypeVariableSignature.java:43) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$2.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:230) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl$2.run(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:218) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.8.0_40]
>       at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getMethods(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:217) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.ClassInfoImpl.getDeclaredMethods(ClassInfoImpl.java:416) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ClassHierarchyResourceVisitor.handleClass(ClassHierarchyResourceVisitor.java:80) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:108) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
>       ... 60 more